# Matlab to Python conversion: Read a text file into numpy records and search array for a string

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am just learning Python and I am not familiar with all the terminology yet.  I have the following Matlab code that I would like to do in Python.

1. Read a text file into a structure (record/list?)
2. Search a field (array of strings) for a particular value.
3. Use that index in another field

**sampleData.txt**

```
name    descript    sr  type    scale   offset
a   Param_a 10  int8    1   0
b   Param_b 20  unit    2   -10
c   Param_c 30  int8    3   -20
d   Param_d 40  int8    4   -30
e   Param_e 50  uint    5   -40
```

**Matlab Code:**

```
>> [info.name info.descrip info.sr info.type info.scale info.offset] = textread('sampleData.txt','%s\t%s\t%f\t%s\t%f\t%f','headerlines',1);

info = 

       name: {5x1 cell}
    descrip: {5x1 cell}
         sr: [5x1 double]
       type: {5x1 cell}
      scale: [5x1 double]
     offset: [5x1 double]

>> nameIdx = strcmp(info.name,'b') ;
>> matched_sr = info.sr(nameIdx)
matched_sr =

20
```

In python I was able to read-in the text file using numpy with:

```
info= recfromcsv('sampleData.txt', delimiter='\t')

Out: 
rec.array([(b'a', b'Param_a', 10, b'int8', 1, 0),
       (b'b', b'Param_b', 20, b'unit', 2, -10),
       (b'c', b'Param_c', 30, b'int8', 3, -20),
       (b'd', b'Param_d', 40, b'int8', 4, -30),
       (b'e', b'Param_e', 50, b'uint', 5, -40)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S1'), ('descript', 'S7'), ('sr', '<i4'), ('type', 'S4'), ('scale', '<i4'), ('offset', '<i4')])
```

I can do things like the following to get an array of logicals:

```
In [77]: info.sr == 20
Out[77]: array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

But the same thing for info.name doesn't work.

```
In [78]: info.name == 'b'
Out[78]: False
```

So, how fo I find a parameter by "name" like I did in matlab with strcmp? Also, more generally is there a better approach in Python/numpy to read in text files as arrays(records or lists?)?  Sorry for any incorrect Python jargon as I am still very new.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `Python3`, which uses unicode strings as default.  But the data file is ASCII, so the strings load as byte arrays.  So all the strings display with the `b`.

So to do comparisons, you need to compare byte strings to byte strings.

Try:

```
info.name == b'b'
```

e.g.

```
In [21]: info.type==b'int8'
Out[21]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Ahhh ... I was just trying to look up what that 'b' meant that was in front of all the elements of the character arrays.  That does clarify things a bit.  And yes I am using python 3.